# Any suggestions on emitting Apache HTTPd access logs to CouchDB?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, logging, couchdb

I'm interested in sending Apache2 access logs directly to CouchDB or some other document storage system.  Do you know of any Apache2 modules that do this, or what options there would be to write one myself?

Comment: Interesting idea, I guess you don't really need normalization to store logs

Comment: What you may wish to look at in logs may change over time, so why tie down a schema?  Also log events are typically not tied together relationally at log event time, but through analysis in reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A start could be [this](http://osdir.com/ml/couchdb-user/2009-06/msg00132.html) [thread](http://osdir.com/ml/couchdb-user/2009-06/msg00135.html).

Answer (score 0):

[mod_ log _sql](http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-logging-to-a-mysql-database-with-mod_log_sql-on-debian-etch) can log directly to MySQL.  When the data is so nicely normalized, why go and toss it all into a key->value system like Couch?

Comment: I guess it's the same reasons why they exist for other uses :). No everything needs to be normalized and key/value dbs have other advantages.

Comment: Sure they do -- but taking perfectly good normalized data and denormalizing it to toss into a blob that you would need to unnormalize later doesn't seem like a great use case for them :).

Comment: why do you assume it would be denormalized?
My intention would be to generate one document per log event, with each document containing each piece of information in the log.

The desire to use such a system is because the data is write heavy, doesn't need transactions, and will be used primarily for data analysis, all things couchdb (and similar systems) excel at.  Not that MySQL can't be setup the same way, just this is where my curiosity currently is.

Answer (score 0):

I've started writing a module which does this it's still at an alpha stage at the moment but you can take a look, I can't confirm it will compile on anything other than Linux at the moment though!
https://sourceforge.net/p/mod-log-couchdb/